# Does downloading a folder/file from steam use as much internet data as the game's files weight?

Tags: internet, download, steam

My brother wants to download a game on steam using a portable internet SIM thingy (same thing as a phone internet access) that weighs about 3 giga bytes, will this download use more than 3Gb of internet data (up to 64 Gb and we are at 56) or more?

Comment: It will likely use less data but it's impossible for us to say one way another without specifics

Comment: its likely that a download will be 66-100% of its size on disk. Many folks say that steam uses download compression but I've not been able to find a satisfactory source for that. Generally speaking, most of the data in the game consists of already compressed assets (textures, video, audio, executables, etc) which cannot be compressed much further, so 2/3 is about the most you could hope for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Generally, No

I download quite a few games on Steam, and the download is often smaller than how much disk space eventually gets used.  (This is probably due to compression.)

I can't recall any games having downloads bigger than the disk space used, but no promises.